# DirectoryNotFoundException even when file does exist

Tags: c#, .net, directory

This is the code:

```
string file = Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, "test.txt");
if (!File.Exists(file)) {
    File.CreateText(file); // will throw always
}

using (var writer = new StreamWriter(file)) { // will throw always
    //...
}
```

This will throw a `DirectoryNotFoundException` if the file doesn't exist and if it attempts to create it, and if the file does exist, then it will throw `DirectoryNotFoundException` when trying to use StreamWriter. I don't believe this code is wrong, so I am at a loss at what is the problem.

**Update**

The value of file is `/tmp/test.txt`. Yes, it always is throwing, the exception is

> System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException`: Could not find a
>   part of the path '/tmp/test.txt'`

### Update

A reboot has fixed this. I have no idea why this was being caused, but it might've simply been an IDE issue.

Comment: Do you have enough permission to access the folder/ directory from code?

Comment: `Environment.CurrentDirectory` should be immediately accessing the code's folder, directly where the solution is, so I do believe it has that much permission. The folder is set for owner, I am owner, and I have read and write permissions.

Comment: `Environment.CurrentDirectory should be immediately accessing the code's folder` That is not a certainty nor is it certain you have permission to access files there. It is better to use the user data folders or temp directories

Comment: I have given the folder permissions for my user to full, so it seems odd that would be it. Nonetheless, I will test this out.

Comment: It fails again. This time, I used `Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), "test.txt");` and it still failed. This should definitely have targetted the temporary path. I'm beginning to suspect there may be an underlying issue with the permissions Rider has. I'm hesitant to try `sudo` on rider, but I'll definitely `sudo` the dotnet command and try to run it that way instead.

Comment: 1) what is the value of `file`? 2) does this always throw: `File.CreateText(file);`? 3) what is the exception?

Comment: The value of `file` is `/tmp/test.txt`. Yes, it always is throwing, the exception is System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path '/tmp/test.txt'`.

Answer (score 2):

You are opening a file with

```
File.CreateText(file);
```

[File.CreateText(String) Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.createtext?view=netframework-4.7.2)

> Returns **StreamWriter** A StreamWriter that writes to the specified file
>   using UTF-8 encoding.

Then you are not closing it. Then you are trying to access the open file by opening it again

```
using (var writer = new StreamWriter(file))
```

However, the exception you are getting is another problem again. When using `StreamWriter`

> **DirectoryNotFoundException** The specified path is invalid (for example,
>   it is on an unmapped drive).

All the above aside, what i suggest you do is

```
string file = Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, "test.txt");
Console.WriteLine(file);

//FileMode.Create will create or overwwrite the file
using (var fs = new FileStream(file,FileMode.Create))
   using (var writer = new StreamWriter(fs))
   { 
   }
```

Then if you still have problems, go to that directory and check if the file is there, check the permissions on the directory and file and make sure you have the appropriate access.

In short your code is suspect and you need to fix it, secondly you need to be sure what file it is your opening, thirdly, you need to check the permissions for that file and or directory

Comment: 1) Excellent point, I don't end up disposing it after creation. I've added that, but the exception is still thrown.
2) I'll try using FileMode.Create and see if it fixes the issue.

Comment: I've tried a reboot, and it has seemingly fixed my issue. I guess some of these issues are well beyond the scope of what I can fix. While I cannot mark this as answer, since this did not solve the issue as it was not caused by the program itself, I thank you for attempting to solve the issue.